# Datatable sorting calculating column in ruby

Tags: jquery, ruby, sorting, datatable

I have problem to sort my column from a calculated value.
Here's the problem:

My datas:

```
def data
    vendors.map do |vendor|
      [
        vendor.image? ? "<img src='#{vendor.image.timeline_thumb.url}' >" : "NO IMAGE" ,
        vendor.name,
        vendor.orders_in_month(Time.zone.today).count,
        count1 = vendor.meals_in_month(Time.zone.today),
        count2 = vendor.meals_in_month(Time.zone.today-1.month),
        count3 = vendor.meals_in_month(Time.zone.today-2.month),
        count1+count2+count3
      ]
    end
  end
```

I want to sort the column with the count1 
so I wrote this:

```
def sort_column
    columns = [
      nil,
      "display_name", 
      nil, 
      HERE THE CODE TO SORT: I tried "count1" count1 or even the calculation, 
      nil, 
      nil, 
      nil
    ]
    columns[params[:iSortCol_0].to_i]
  end
```

and in my js:

```
aoColumns: [    
                false,
                { "asSorting": [ "asc","desc" ] },
                null,
                { "asSorting": [ "asc","desc" ] },
                null,
                null,
                null
            ]
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: So, you have a problem, but you don't say what it is. Nor do you give us data so we can reproduce the problem on our own. "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance."

Comment: Sorry, I maybe wrote it to fast, the problem is that when I'm trying to sort this column (or another calculated one, like the last one) the table doenst display anything when I write something in the def sort_column. I just wanted to know if someone already tried ti sort a calcultated column